# Seeking tools to create tree of specific individuals in gedcom

Tags: gedcom, family-tree, software-recommendations

I am trying to help an adoptee determine his birth parents based on DNA matches at different sites. I became involved because he is a 1st-3rd cousin DNA match to many people in my extensive family tree. To help sort through the data, I would like to create a family tree diagram (online or on paper) that only includes people whose DNA has been tested, or their common ancestors. I am willing to mark which people I wish to include in the tree. Is there software that will help me create such a tree, ideally using my gedcom file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most **FT** software allows the export of some or all of the people from a **Gedcom** file. If your software allows this then select the people for export into a new **DNA gedcom**. Then open a new project in your **FT** software using that **DNA gedcom** as the source data.

If your software does not allow that partial export then have a look at some of the other FT programmes. **Family Historian**, which I use, has this facility. There may be some online Gedcom editors that allow this too.